# SAP PI: Graphical mapping: Map with default function not working

Tags: mapping, sap-pi, idoc, sap-xi

***Scenario:***

Address node has 6-7 fields which has customer details. In default we have 4 partner functions that is coming in IDoc that we map it to target fields. In some scenario, there are additional partner functions will be present in IDoc, where the address for them is fetched from separate node `YLKNA1M`. So our mapping for `address1` & `address 2` is:

[image: address1 mapping]

If `YLKNA1M` node is there, then it is treated as additional partner function and under that node `STRAS_HOUSN` field is passed to it, otherwise `STRAS_HOUSN` in `YLF_CIN` node (default partner function) is passed.

***Issue:***

When the `STRAS_HOUSN` field is not available in `YLKNA1M`, the `address1` field is disappearing. Not showing in output XML.

I want an empty tag in that place if value not present in IDoc. I tried placing map with default at various places in that mapping. Still address1 is not showing with empty field (it should show like `<Address1></Address1>`).

What can be done for this ?